# React Native state console.log

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-state

I am using firebase for my app and the data i read i want to put that in state to use it in different places.

it kinda works but when i want to console.log the state it updates like 30 times a second, am i doing something wrong?

this is my code

```
  const db = firebase.firestore();
  
  const [PBS1Detail, setPBS1Detail] = useState();

  db.collection('Track').get().then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
      renderTracks(doc)
      }
    )
});
    const renderTracks = (doc) => {
    let data = doc.data().data[0].Module;
    return setPBS1Detail(data);
    }

    console.log(PBS1Detail)
```

i already tried to store it in a variable instead of state but thats not working for me, i can't get the variable from the function global

i am a noob i get it xd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a return statement when setting state. Also, it looks like you're performing some async function which means that when your component renders for the first time, PBS1Detail will be undefined since the db is a pending Promise.

You could/should put your async functions in useEffect hook:

```
useEffect(()=> {
db.collection('Track').get().then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
      renderTracks(doc)
      }
    )
});
}, [])

 const renderTracks = (doc) => {
    let data = doc.data().data[0].Module;
    setPBS1Detail(data);
 }
```

Finally, your renderTracks function doesn't seem correct as it appears you're looping over docs and resetting your state each time.

Instead, maybe consider having an array for PBS1Detail

```
const [PBS1Detail, setPBS1Detail] = useState([]);
```

Then modify your async call:

```
useEffect(()=> {
db.collection('Track').get().then((snapshot) => {
    let results = []
    snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
      results.push(renderTracks(doc))
      }
    )
    setPBS1Detail(results)
});
}, [])

 const renderTracks = (doc) => {
   return doc.data().data[0].Module;
 }
```

This way you're only setting state once and thus avoiding unnecessary re-renders and you're saving all of your docs instead of overwriting them.

Comment: I'm glad it's fixed! Please consider marking this as the correct answer.